# spring/hibernate mysql configuration for get best performance

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache

How should I configure mysql driver and hibernate properties in applicaton-context.xml for get best performance? Do you have any suggestions for improvement? and What do you say to that my configurations? 
***application-context.xml***

```
<!-- Data Source Declaration -->
<bean id="DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oys?characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
<bean id="SessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    scope="singleton">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>spring.dao</value>
            <value>spring.model</value>
            <value>spring.service</value>
            <value>spring.other</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/myehcache.xml</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

***myehcache.xml***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/ehcache" />

    <defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </defaultCache>
m
    <cache name="forExample" maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="5" timeToLiveSeconds="10">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="5" eternal="false" timeToLiveSeconds="120">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000" eternal="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

pom.xml

```
<spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
<spring.webflow.version>2.4.1.RELEASE</spring.webflow.version>
<myfaces.version>2.2.7</myfaces.version>
<hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version
<commons.dbcp.version>1.4</commons.dbcp.version>
<mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
```

I'm current working local machine(16gb Ram,i7,ssd disk).And I want to get best performance from my web application.But I do not have sufficient knowledge and experience for the job.Please give me advice for it.(version,driver class,hibernate properties,ehcache properties..etc) Thanks in advice..

Answer (score 2):

Hi I will try to suggest somethings I think can lead to better performance:-

1. **Reduce primary key generation overhead**
In processes that are 'insert-intensive', the choice of a primary key generation strategy can matter a lot. One common way to generate id's is to use database sequences, usually one per table
2. **Use JDBC batch inserts/updates**
For batch programs, JDBC drivers usually provide an optimization for reducing network round-trips named 'JDBC batch inserts/updates'
This is the entity manager factory configuration needed to active batch inserts/updates:

```
 <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">150</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
```

Setting only the JDBC batch size won't work
3. **Periodically flush and clear the Hibernate session**
 Long-running sessions should be avoided as much as possible, but if by some reason they are needed, this is how to contain memory consumption:

```
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.clear();
```

The flush will trigger the inserts from new entities to be sent to the database. The clear releases the new entities from the session.
4. **Reduce Hibernate dirty-checking overhead**
Hibernate uses internally a mechanism to keep track of modified entities called dirty-checking.
Hibernate does it's most to keep the performance cost of dirty-checking to a minimum, and to dirty-check only when it needs to, but the mechanism does have a cost, which is more noticeable in tables with a large number of columns.One way is

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public void someMethod() {}
```

[Ways to avoid dirty checking](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html#d0e1932)
5. **Use the second-level and query caches**
If some data is identified as being eligible for caching,try using second level cache.
 [Setup and disadvantages of second level cache](http://blog.jhades.org/setup-and-gotchas-of-the-hibernate-second-level-and-query-caches/)

6. **Search for 'bad' querys**
Bad queries are like for e.g.
Full table scans: they happen when the table is being fully scanned.try some projection
Full cartesian joins: This means that the full cartesian product of several tables is being computed.
7. **Review table indexes.**
  As your application and schema grows, checking indexes become more complex and your ORM tool cannot automatically define the indexes for you. To review your indexes, enable show_sql and check the SQL statements if attributes in where clause have proper indexes. Also, review that indexes are created on foreign keys. In short, do not trust that your ORM tool will automatically define the indexes for you.If possible, make your indexed columns not-nullable.